# querying v$session table in unix

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, connection

I am trying the following in unix:

```
count=sqlplus -s ${DB_USER}/${DB_PASS}@${DB_INST} << END
set echo off head off verify off feed off pages 0 lin 120
select COUNT(USERNAME) from v$session where status not in ('INACTIVE') and osuser not in ('oracle');
exit;
END
echo $count
```

But it is evaluating `$session` as null and just querying table `"v"`. Any way to query this table in unix.

Comment: Did you define the `$session` variable?

Comment: v$session is a table in oracle.

Comment: Then this is trying to evaluate the `v$session` in shell, so that it gets interpreted as `v` + `$session` value. You may have to escape the `$` so that it is treated literally.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `bash`, if you quote your *heredoc* termination string (i.e.: `<< 'END'`) you will prevent shell expansion of `$...`

```
count=sqlplus -s ${DB_USER}/${DB_PASS}@${DB_INST} << 'END'
set echo off head off verify off feed off pages 0 lin 120
select COUNT(USERNAME) from v$session where status not in ('INACTIVE') and osuser not in ('oracle');
exit;
END
echo $count
```

---

From `man bash`:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>               <<[-]word
>                       here-document
>               delimiter
> ```
>
> If  word is  unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  character  sequence  \  is  ignored, and \ must be used to quote the  characters \, $, and `.